# If an ASP page takes too long to load, notify me

Tags: html, iis, asp-classic

We have a Development box in our environment that will soon be moving to a Production environment. It is written in classic asp. One of the mandates as part of the disaster recovery plan is to ensure that if there is a problem loading the page, to notify the site admins. I know how to send the notification as we have a mail processor which is used to send out communications, but I am looking for help on how to do sort of like an IF statement, that if the page hasn't finished loading in x seconds, to email the site admins and continue loading the page until either it completes loading or times out. Again, we are not having any issues as of now, but we need to have something in place should there be any future problems. Again, this is done in classic asp.

So an example (30 being seconds to load):

```
If ServerScriptTimeout > 30 Then
  response.write "Page is taking longer to load admins, please investigate"
Else
End If
```

Would something like this work or even be possible?

We use IIS7 on our Server

Thank you in advance for ur help.

UPDATE - just to add. We already have splash pages and notifications ready should there be a connection issue with one of our database connections. It validates the connection and then does a test query. If either of those fail, it provides the site admins with an update. I would like a similar option for page load time. I already have a script timeout in place, but wasn't sure if the script time out can work with an if statement to do something after x seconds passes before the timeout is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to turn on IIS Logging and make sure you enable the `time-taken`, which is recorded in milli-seconds.

Now you can then either create a program or log parsers to monitor the IIS logs or use an IIS Log monitoring software and just set up alerts to page out if the time-take is over 30000 milliseconds.

There are numerous tools that do this, just do a search for one that will fit your needs.

Doing it in the code itself, if it times out then you will never get the alert, so I don't think that's the option you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Going by your fourth paragraph, what if I program it before the timeout occurs? So lets say the timeout is set to expire at 60 seconds. If I program it notify the site admins after 30 has passed, u think that is doable? I guess where I am struggling is if I need to do this from the local side or keep it server side written.

Comment: How can you be 100% certain your code will execute? Javascript runs on the client side, so you'll never get notified unless you have it call a webapi to notify you.  Another way you can do it, if this is an external site, will be to create an account at uptimerobot.com and do keyword monitoring and if the keyword doesn't show on the page, you'll get alerted.

Answer (score 1):

One option some sites use is for another application to regularly do a GET on landing page and if it fails to load or takes to long to send an alert.

There are plenty of third party services that offer this, search for "page availability test", or if you want it internal it would not be that hard to write.  But the key point is that it has to be external to the IIS server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not think our company handles using 3rd parties very well, security is tight, and getting approvals is near impossible lol. Which is why they want me to write it out. So, I am wondering if I can extend the use of ScriptTimeout and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have figured this out. Please provide your feedback on this if you wish to.

```
'Beginning of the page`
  Starttime = Timer()


  Do Until i=5382343
        i=i+1
  Loop

  'Body of the page here


  'at the bottom, type this in
   TimeTest = (Timer - Starttime)

    If TimeTest > 30.500000 Then
    response.write "SLOW, Admins Notified"
    Else
    response.write "FAST"
    End If

    Response.Write("<br>The page was generated in : " & (Timer - Starttime) & " seconds.")
```